# How to solve Android Resolver ERROR in Unity?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am making a Unity 2D mobile game while also testing mobile ads using Goggle Admob. So the game is at a playable state, I installed the package, I am running the android resolver adn I get this ERROR:

"ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-8.0.282.8-hotspot"

> Full Error: Reporting analytics data: /androidresolver/resolve/gradle/failed/fetch?unityVersion=2021.3.0f1&unityPlatform=WindowsEditor&installSource=unitypackage&version=1.2.171&scope= 'Android Resolver: Gradle Resolve: Tool Extraction Failed'
> ERROR: Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.
> Failed to run 'F:\Unity\Projects\Floppy Bert\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "F:\Unity\Projects\Floppy Bert\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=F:\Unity\2021.3.0f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=F:\Unity\Projects\Floppy Bert\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=0" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=4.0.1"'
> stdout:
> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-8.0.282.8-hotspot
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
> location of your Java installation.
> stderr:

Any Ideas on what I should do ? I am literally clueless. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I got a smiliar problem, and there is my solution:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", androidJavaHome);

// TODO android process

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", unityJavaHome);
```

The reason is that JavaHome for Unity is diffrent from JavaHome for Android.